# unpivot() with additional information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

i have some data like:

```
t   starttime                 endtime

1   2012-11-13 07:00:00.000   2012-11-13 09:00:00.000
1   2012-11-13 09:00:00.000   2012-11-13 09:15:00.000
2   2012-11-13 09:00:00.000   2012-11-13 16:00:00.000
1   2012-11-13 09:15:00.000   2012-11-13 12:00:00.000
1   2012-11-13 12:30:00.000   2012-11-13 15:00:00.000
1   2012-11-14 07:00:00.000   2012-11-14 09:00:00.000
1   2012-11-14 09:00:00.000   2012-11-14 09:15:00.000
1   2012-11-14 09:15:00.000   2012-11-14 12:00:00.000
1   2012-11-14 12:30:00.000   2012-11-14 15:00:00.000
1   2012-11-15 07:00:00.000   2012-11-15 09:00:00.000
1   2012-11-15 09:00:00.000   2012-11-15 09:15:00.000
1   2012-11-15 09:15:00.000   2012-11-15 12:00:00.000
1   2012-11-15 12:30:00.000   2012-11-15 15:00:00.000
```

and want to get it preprcessed like:

```
timestamp               t   x

2012-11-13 07:00:00.000 1   1
2012-11-13 09:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-13 09:00:00.000 1   1
2012-11-13 09:00:00.000 2   1
2012-11-13 09:15:00.000 1   0
2012-11-13 09:15:00.000 1   1
2012-11-13 12:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-13 12:30:00.000 1   1
2012-11-13 15:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-13 16:00:00.000 2   0
2012-11-14 07:00:00.000 1   1
2012-11-14 09:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-14 09:00:00.000 1   1
2012-11-14 09:15:00.000 1   0
2012-11-14 09:15:00.000 1   1
2012-11-14 12:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-14 12:30:00.000 1   1
2012-11-14 15:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-15 07:00:00.000 1   1
2012-11-15 09:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-15 09:00:00.000 1   1
2012-11-15 09:15:00.000 1   0
2012-11-15 09:15:00.000 1   1
2012-11-15 12:00:00.000 1   0
2012-11-15 12:30:00.000 1   1
2012-11-15 15:00:00.000 1   0
```

`x` should define, if value of `timestamp` is from `starttime` ( x = 1 ) or from `endtime` ( x = 0 ).
i know, it's piece of cake, using two `selects` with an `union all`.

but i'm wondering **if it is possible using `unpivot()`** with some extensions?
started like:

```
SELECT 
    , UD."timeStamp"
    , UD."t"
    , "isStart"
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
              "StartTime"
            , "EndTime"
            , "t"
            , < REFERENCE TO STARTTIME OR ENDTIME ? >
        FROM 
            Data 
    ) AS BC
UNPIVOT ( "timeStamp" FOR dummy IN ( "StartTime", "EndTime" )) AS UD
```

`< REFERENCE TO STARTTIME OR ENDTIME ? >` should give the information, from which column timeStamp comes from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, just apply a `CASE` statement to it:

```
select timestamp,
  t,
  case when col = 'starttime' then 1 else 0 end x
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  timestamp for col in (starttime, endtime)
) un
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e95b3/2)

If you don't use the `CASE` statement the `col` field just displays either the value `starttime` or `endtime`.

Result:

```
|                       TIMESTAMP | T | X |
-------------------------------------------
| November, 13 2012 07:00:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 13 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 13 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 13 2012 09:15:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 13 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 2 | 1 |
| November, 13 2012 16:00:00+0000 | 2 | 0 |
| November, 13 2012 09:15:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 13 2012 12:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 13 2012 12:30:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 13 2012 15:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 14 2012 07:00:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 14 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 14 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 14 2012 09:15:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 14 2012 09:15:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 14 2012 12:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 14 2012 12:30:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 14 2012 15:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 15 2012 07:00:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 15 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 15 2012 09:00:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 15 2012 09:15:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 15 2012 09:15:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 15 2012 12:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
| November, 15 2012 12:30:00+0000 | 1 | 1 |
| November, 15 2012 15:00:00+0000 | 1 | 0 |
```